# Converting variables using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How I can convert variables using dplyr? Below code gives me:

> All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.

```
mutate(superstore, Order.Date = as.Date(select(superstore, Order.Date)))
```

Data:

```
download.file('https://github.com/ywchiu/rcookbook/raw/master/chapter7/superstore_sales.csv', 'superstore_sales.csv')
```

Comment: `mutate(superstore, Order.Date = as.Date(Order.Date))` works.

Comment: Why not `mutate(superstore, Order.Date = as.Date(Order.Date))`? Because `select(superstore, Order.Date)` selects ALL dates ...

Comment: Are you looking to convert the Order.Date variable datatype from Factor to Date.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to select the parameter you want to mutate. The code following would do (after you download the file to local directory):

```
library(read)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- read.csv("./superstore_sales.csv")
df <- mutate(df, Order.Date = as.Date(Order.Date))
```

Hope this could help.